# Flink nested classes toDataStream conversion error

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-table-api

I am using flink 1.13. I am trying to convert table results to the datastream in a following way but keep getting error.

```
public class HybridTrial {
  public static class Address {
    public String street;
    public String houseNumber;

    public Address() {}

    public Address(String street, String houseNumber) {
      this.street = street;
      this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
    }
  }

  public static class User {
    public String name;

    public Integer score;

    public LocalDateTime event_time;

    public Address address;

    // default constructor for DataStream API
    public User() {}

    // fully assigning constructor for Table API
    public User(String name, Integer score, LocalDateTime event_time, Address address) {
      this.name = name;
      this.score = score;
      this.event_time = event_time;
      this.address = address;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    DataStream<User> dataStream =
        env.fromElements(
                new User("Alice", 4, LocalDateTime.now(), new Address()),
                new User("Bob", 6, LocalDateTime.now(), new Address("NBC", "204")),
                new User("Alice", 10, LocalDateTime.now(), new Address("ABC", "1033")))
            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
                WatermarkStrategy.<User>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(60)));

    StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);
    Table table =
        tableEnv.fromDataStream(
            dataStream, Schema.newBuilder().build());

    table.printSchema();

    Table t = table.select($("*"));

    DataStream<User> dsRow = tableEnv.toDataStream(t,User.class);
    dsRow.print();

    env.execute();
  }
}
```

Error I got is :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Column types of query result and sink for registered table 'default_catalog.default_database.Unregistered_DataStream_Sink_1' do not match.
Cause: Incompatible types for sink column 'event_time' at position 2.

Query schema: [name: STRING, score: INT, event_time: RAW('java.time.LocalDateTime', '...'), address: *flinkSqlExperiments.HybridTrial$Address<`street` STRING, `houseNumber` STRING>*]
Sink schema:  [name: STRING, score: INT, event_time: TIMESTAMP(9), address: *flinkSqlExperiments.HybridTrial$Address<`street` STRING, `houseNumber` STRING>*]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.connectors.DynamicSinkUtils.createSchemaMismatchException(DynamicSinkUtils.java:437)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.connectors.DynamicSinkUtils.validateSchemaAndApplyImplicitCast(DynamicSinkUtils.java:256)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.connectors.DynamicSinkUtils.convertSinkToRel(DynamicSinkUtils.java:198)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.connectors.DynamicSinkUtils.convertExternalToRel(DynamicSinkUtils.java:143)
```

I tried with custom conversion from DataStream to table as well but while converting from table to DataStream still run into error. I am stuck so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The automatic, reflection-based type extraction in DataStream is not as powerful as the one of the Table API. This is also due to state backwards compatibility issues in the DataStream API.

The `event_time` field is a `GenericType` in DataStream API which results in `RAW` in Table API. You have the following possibilities:

- Give a proper `TypeInformation` in `fromElements`
- Override the `TypeInformation` using `DataType` in `fromDataStream`

Answer (score 0):

It solved my issue by registering a POJO using the below method

> env.getConfig().registerPojoType(YourClass.class);

You can use any user-defined DTO and register as a POJO